# How can I run my bower-angular project?

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower

Hi everyone I know its simple question but I am new the angular development.

I have angular projects but I cant run.

I know npm using on console, I tried many times npm run, npm instal on my main directory.

So, how can I run my angular project on the console?

Comment: so why do you want to run a front-end framework at back-end?

Answer (score 1):

If the project is using [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) or is similarly configured, you can use

```
npm start
```

to install dependencies and start a running http-server on port 8080 (by default).

If you project has a `README` or `package.json` file, it might give more clues.

Otherwise you can just serve up the application with `http-server`:

```
npm install http-server
http-server .
```

Answer (score 0):

Asume you are using NodeJS as a server side, try `node [your-application-main-js-file.js]`. For example `node index.js`. But it depends on what back end environment are you using. Angular is just a front end library/ framework. It should be tested on browser not in your console.

Comment: hi, thank you. In the main directory just i have this js "karma.conf.js" I run this command node karma.conf.js at the main directory. but nothing happen...

Comment: Which seed or repository did you clone? Maybe I can help to look at it.